# List syntax with custom list type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, recursive-datastructures

Given a custom type of lists such as

```
data List' a = EmptyList | NonEmptyList a (List' a)
           deriving Show
```

and a function to tell if such a list is non-empty

```
null' xs = case xs of
  EmptyList -> True
  _ -> False
```

why doesn't calling it in GHCi with list arguments like

```
null' NonEmptyList [1,2,3]
```

or

```
null' EmptyList []
```

work?  Calling the function with the constructors defined does work.

```
null' Emptylist
```

Why is this?

Comment: What do you expect to happen here? You're giving `null'` two arguments. `null'` takes one argument and returns a list.

Comment: for null' function yes, but for append' as you can see i expect it to give me one appended list.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're mixing up built-in syntax (i.e. the thing with the square brackets) with your own lists. You would write `NonEmptyList 1 (NonEmptyList 2 (NonEmptyList 3 EmptyList)))` to make your own list. No square brackets involved.

Comment: I don't follow... You should specify exactly: * what you're doing; * what you expect (and maybe why); * what happened.

Comment: IOW start by implementing `fromList :: [a] -> List' a`, and maybe also  `toList :: List' a -> [a]`.

Comment: @shachaf: Can you put that down as a real answer?

Answer (score 3):

Like shachaf mentioned, your list type is not the same as Haskell's list type provided in the Prelude.  That means that you cannot use list bracket syntax for your custom list type unless you use the `OverloadedLists` language extension, which you can read more about [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/OverloadedLists).

However, let's assume for a moment that you don't overload list syntax.  Then the only way you can invoke your `null'` function is with the constructors you defined:

```
>>> null' EmptyList
True
>>> null' (NonEmptyList 1 (NonEmptyList 2 EmptyList))
False
```